выпадающие списки через DataValidationBuilder с диапазоном-данных в относительных ссылках
На листе создаю выпадающие списки скриптом через DataValidationBuilder вот по такому шаблону:
// Устанавливает выпадающий список в ячейку A1 и требует совпадения значения с
// диапазоном B1:B10, дополняя поле выпадающим списком.
var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1');
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('B1:B10');
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(range).build();
cell.setDataValidation(rule);

естественно, подставляя свои данные. При этом в получившемся на листе списке,ссылка на диапазон - источник получается в абсолютном виде, см. рисунок

Вопрос: есть ли возможность создавать выпадающие списки через  DataValidationBuilder с диапазоном в относительных ссылках?

Нет, нельзя.
Так как в этом нет никакого смысла и логики, и, как по мне, нет практического применения.
Единственное для чего это может пригодиться, это копирование ячеек с настроенной Проверкой данных, чтобы при копировании ссылка на диапазон автоматически переносилась относительно...  Но это очень редкое и довольно сложно-скользкое применение, которое в конечном итоге, можно решить с помощью скриптов для каждого конкретного случая.
Сам внутренний функционал системы "Проверки данных" автоматически переводит ссылки в абсолютные.

Спасибо за ответ.  "Единственное для чего это может пригодиться, это копирование ячеек с настроенной Проверкой данных, чтобы при копировании ссылка на диапазон автоматически переносилась относительно" - именно для этого и нужно. Я хотел вставлять список на лист и "растягивать" его скриптом, так быстрее, если я не ошибаюсь

Еще раз повторюсь, что такой "сценарий" довольно сложный  алгоритм.
Кроме того, я даже представить себе не могу какой-то вариант такой необходимости.
Возможно следует пересмотреть саму задачу и конечные цели такой задачи.  100% уверен, что такую задачу можно решить другим способом, потому что сам сервис "Проверка данных" имеет конкретные цели и четкие внутри-функциональные  реализации.
Слава богу, что этот сервис развивается самим Гуглом.  Для примера появилась множественность выбора из списка.  Это здорово.
Но и с помощью скриптов многие расширяют функционал этого сервиса.

Возможно Вы правы. В двух словах трудно обрисовать ( это файл подбора оборудования для инженеров). Сейчас я эту задачу (с "растягиванием" списков) реализую через циклы. "появилась множественность выбора из списка" - Вы, кст, не знаете: она доступна через скрипт?

Если я правильно понял задачу вам нужно расширять диапазон данных, который храниться в списке. Мне помог такой способ: я вручную добавлял ячейку перед последним элементом списка и туда прописывал значение и таблица сама растягивала диапазон данных в списках.

Нет, к сожалению, как правильно заметил BotYourBiz задача это: копирование ячеек с настроенной Проверкой данных, чтобы при копировании ссылка на диапазон автоматически переносилась относительно. Но все равно - спасибо)

С радостью хочу сообщить, что появилось решение вашего вопроса.
Один парень проделал очень интересный эсперимент и у него получилось обмануть систему "Проверка данных" (по другому и никак не могу это охарактеризовать) и настроить их в относительных ссылках.
Единственное, что сделал он это не через скрипт, а прямо в таблице.
Но его решение уникально для многих задач при работе с таблицами.
Фишка заключается вот  в чем:
1.Надо настроить одну ячейку на "Проверку данных". Это можно сделать через


Затем выбрать перенастройку ячейки через "ручку" выпадающего списка


И уже в этом режиме настроить диапазон в относительных ссылках.  При этом желательно даже не нажимать кнопку "Готово", а просто выбрать другую ячейку в таблице. В этом случае система "Проверки данных" не переделает ссылку на абсолютную.



Теперь эту ячейку можно копировать в любое другое место и настройка "Проверки данных" будет меняться относительно новых позиций...  Шикарный вариант... Буду его использовать во многих задачах...
Кроме того ссылку можно набирать в разных вариантах:
H9:H14, или $H9:$H14, или H$9:H$14 и другие вариации.
Думаю, что эта информация должна точно помочь в ваших задачах

Но в таком случае (если я правильно понял реализацию) мы не сможем менять глубину диапазона через скрипт? Или я ошибаюсь?

Объясните, что подразумевается под глубиной диапазона:

это расширение по горизонтали
или по вертикали
или в обоих направлениях. ?

Немного экспериментировал с изменением диапазона через скрипты.
Но, пока что всегда Гугл самостоятельно исправлял все относительные ссылки на абсолютные.
Есть еще пару идей, которые нужно проверить. Будет время - сделаю.
Но на текущий момент "найденный вариант обхода" исправления для себя считаю уникальным и уже внедряю в некоторые проекты.
Даже можно реализовать сложнейшие структуры выпадающих списков с 3-4-5 мерными вложениями.

Под глубиной подразумеваю количество элементов списка. Т.е это - расширение по горизонтали. Первое, что пришло на ум, это: попробовать вставлять строки в диапазон, охватываемый "базовым" - преднастроенным списком. Но нужно проверить. В любом случае - низкий поклон за приём! ))

Но на текущий момент "найденный вариант обхода" исправления, для себя, считаю уникальным и уже внедряю в некоторые проекты. Даже можно реализовать сложнейшие структуры выпадающих списков с 3-4-5 мерными вложениями.
Быстро, круто, полезно и эффектно. 

